# fetch request - SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data

Tags: json, async-await, fetch

I am learning js and fetch API. I'm attempting to fetch some exchange rate data from a banks API endpoint. I can't figure out why I am unable to parse the response body into JSON. My code is:

```
const getRate = async () => {

    const data = await fetch(url)
    const rateData = await data.json()
    console.log(rateData)
}
```

LOG: Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data

If I ran the same url in firefox browser I get the same error message under JSON. But under 'Raw Data' I see the response text exactly like the example in the banks API documentation.

[image]

EDIT: I ran the response raw data through json linter and it shows syntax error for all white spaces. Could this be the issue?

Comment: what is `Content-type` header value in the response ?

Comment: application/json

Comment: Content-Type application/json; charset=utf-16

Comment: interesting, browsers generally expect `utf-8` encoded data. I think the issue is because it is  `utf-16` encoded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is because the response is `utf-16` encoded. Browsers generally expect `utf-8` encoding. One way to handle is to use `TextDecoder`:

```
const getRate = async () => {
    let r = await fetch(url);
    let buff = await r.arrayBuffer();
    let decoder = new TextDecoder('utf-16');
    let rateData = JSON.parse(decoder.decode(buff));
    
    console.log(rateData);
}
```